# Expanding $\frac{(\text{cis}\ 75^\circ-\text{cis}\ 155^\circ)(1-\cos 8^\circ+i \sin 8 ^\circ)}{2-2\cos 8^\circ}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

The expression $$\dfrac{(\text{cis}\ 75^\circ-\text{cis}\ 155^\circ)(1-\cos 8^\circ+i \sin 8 ^\circ)}{2-2\cos 8^\circ}$$ can be written as $r\ \text{cis}\ \theta,$ where $0 \le \theta < 360^\circ$. Find $\theta$ in degrees.

---

I expanded the numerator to $$\text{cis}\ 75^\circ-\text{cis}\ 75^\circ\cos 8 ^\circ+i \ \text{cis}\ 75^\circ\sin 8^\circ-\text{cis}\ 155^\circ+\text{cis}\ 155^\circ \cos 8^\circ-i \ \text{cis}\ 155^\circ\sin 8^\circ.$$
But I don't think I can simplify anymore.  Is my approach a dead end or did I miss some trig identities?

*For those that are unfamiliar with $\text{cis}$, $\text{cis} \ \theta=\cos \theta+i \sin \theta$.

Comment: It might be clear or if you wrote $\mathrm{cis}$ in exponential form.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding is here not the easiest solution strategy, better combine terms.
$$
e^{i·75^∘}-e^{i·155^∘}=-e^{i·115^∘}·2i\sin(40^∘),
$$
and
$$
1-e^{-i·8^∘}=e^{-i·4^∘}·2i\sin(4^∘).
$$
and in general
$$
e^{ib}-e^{ia}=e^{i\frac{b+a}2}·2i\sin\frac{b-a}2
$$